# перенаправление маршрутов в laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Имею маршрут следующего вида:

```
 Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

он перенаправляет их через функцию

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

как можно перенаправить маршрут на другую страницу? Пытался исполльзовать обычный запрос вида

```
Route::redirect('/logout', '/auth/login', 301);
```

или даже так

```
Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout', function(){
return view('auth.login');
});
```

но к сожалению что-то не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Редирект используется внутри анонимного метода (или метода контроллера)

```
Route::get('/logout',function(){
 \Auth::logout();
 return redirect('/auth/login');
});
```

2) Во втором вы делаете вообще что то уникальное, вы и пытаетесь обработчик указать и анонимный метод вызвать, определитесь что должен обработать маршрут.

И Совет прочтите сперва документацию, просто от начала до конца, что б иметь общие понятие о том как это все работает.

Comment: Хорошо, почитаю. Я по разному пытался и ваш код также был у меня в попытках, но без использования Auth::logout();. К сожалению, код почему-то не хочет работать.

Comment: а вы авторизацию вообще сделали ? путь есть ? какую он у вас ошибку выдает ?

Comment: все работает теперь, у вас опечатка видимо, одинарное двоеточие стоит. Спасибо!